# Flutter NestedScrollView with TabBarView scrolls way too much when the body content is less

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here is the scenario -

1. Need TabBarView as user can swipe to change the screen.
2. Want to load more items when user scrolls to the bottom of the screen.

The first code is the NestedScrollView with TabBarView which has two tabs containing listview with 4 items. Even though the body height is less than screen height the body scrolls. I understand the default height is set to view port height but if I want achieve point number 2, I cant since the scroll is way too much. Is there a way to wrap the body to the height of the content?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Nested Scroll Demo with TabBarView',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: NestedScrollViewTest(),
    );
  }
}

class NestedScrollViewTest extends StatelessWidget {
  const NestedScrollViewTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _tabs = ["One", "Two"];
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: _tabs.length, // This is the number of tabs.
        child: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                sliver: SliverAppBar(
                  forceElevated: true,
                  elevation: 2.0,
                  primary: true,
                  pinned: true,
                  stretch: true,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  expandedHeight: 500,
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
                    centerTitle: true,
                    background: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 4,
                          child: AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 5,
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.amber,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: TabBarView(
            children: _tabs.map((String name) {
              return SafeArea(
                top: false,
                bottom: false,
                child: Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return CustomScrollView(
                      // shrinkWrap: true, // even with this it is not working.
                      key: PageStorageKey<String>(name),
                      slivers: <Widget>[
                        SliverOverlapInjector(
                          handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                        ),
                        SliverPadding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          sliver: SliverFixedExtentList(
                            itemExtent: 48.0,
                            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return ListTile(
                                  title: Text('Item $index'),
                                );
                              },
                              childCount: 4,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the second code, I am using a CustomScrollView instead. Here since there is no SliverTabBarView, I am using a SliverFillRemaining widget to wrap the TabBarView and place it in the CustomScrollView. Even here the body scrolls way too much since SliverFillRemaining default height is view port height. Without using the TabBarView the CustomScrollView wraps the body based on the height of the content but I need TabBarView.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Nested Scroll Demo with TabBarView',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CustomScrollViewTest(),
    );
  }
}

class CustomScrollViewTest extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomScrollViewTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _tabs = ["One", "Two"];
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: _tabs.length, // This is the number of tabs.
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              forceElevated: true,
              elevation: 2.0,
              primary: true,
              pinned: true,
              stretch: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              expandedHeight: 500,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
                centerTitle: true,
                background: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 4,
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 5,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverFillRemaining(
              // hasScrollBody: false,
              child: TabBarView(
                children: _tabs.map((String name) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text('Item $index'),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: 4,
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Steps I have tried,

1. If I change the property hasScrollBody: false in SliverFillRemaining, I get the error -

```
RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.
```

2. If I use SliverToBoxAdapter instead of SliverFillRemaining then I get this error since TabBarView height is dependent on the parent.

```
Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.
```

Is there a way to wrap the content based on the body height keeping TabBarView in mind.

Edit: adding images -

> Initial

[image: initial]

> start scroll

[image: scroll start]

> end scroll

[image: scroll end]

Comment: can you add images of what you want & what actually you have achieved so far?

Comment: @TaqiTahmidTanzil added images for reference

Comment: @ShashiKiran could you solve your problem?